# MacbookAir 3,1 (late 2010) suspension under Kubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Tags: kubuntu, suspend, openbox, xfce4-power-manager

So finally I managed to configure Openbox desktop properly on this laptop. Everything works OK except I can't figure how to set up suspension to work as it should.
I've installed xfce4-power-manager which doesn't seem to work properly, meaning for example display power management settings are ignored. The setting that I care about the most is when lid closed -> suspend. and it is working but after opening the lid the computer doesn't respond I can only force shutdown. Any solutions for this model under Kubuntu 16.04

Any help would be appreciated.
thanks.

Comment: Openbox is a window manager, not a desktop. Kwin is Kubuntu's default manager. Kubuntu has its own power manager. So what you seem to have is quite complex and possibly has led to some conflict.

Comment: Hey, I've just "used" Kubuntu as the base, I'm not using any KDE/Plasma components under my Openbox session. Like I said i'm trying to use xfce4-power-manager and most of the settings are ignored, most importantly the lid closes settings which works, but the computer refuses to wake up.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I couldn't find an answer for this. pm-suspend works but the computer doesn't wake up after suspension. I've tested pm-hibernate which works. from there I'm searched for solutions as why xfce4-power-manger settings are ignored, in short - in /etc/systemd/logind.conf - I've removed the # from HandleLidSwitch and changed "suspend" to "hibernate" Now the setting Laptop Lid = Suspend actually Hibernates now.